# how to restrict my latest version of image in image definition from users in Azure compute gallery for a particular time

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-image-builder

I am deploying my hardening images in Azure compute galleries and then from that image of latest version creating virtual machine and after creating virtual machine scanning through Prisma Scan/ Qualys Scan, so I want to restrict my images version so that no one can use those till scan is   done. So please suggest me how to restrict my latest version of image in image definition from users.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag called "excludeFromLatest" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/gallery-image-versions/get#galleryimageversionpublishingprofile

*excludeFromLatest

boolean
If set to true, Virtual Machines deployed from the latest version of the Image Definition won't use this Image Version.*